# Is there a penalty for rolling consecutive tens?

Tags: house-rules, dice, l5r

In 2nd edition Legend of the Five Rings, is there a penalty for rolling too many tens in a row (like in monopoly for rolling doubles 3 times in a row)?

For some reason I'm convinced there is, but it might have been a house rule when I played years ago...

Comment: Just as a side note...why would there be a penalty for this? Why on earth would you penalise someone for being too lucky??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Under the standard rules, each dice keeps exploding until you stop rolling 10s.

Remember that each dice explodes seperately. If you have 3k2 and roll 10, 10, 6 then you get to reroll the 10s. Say they come up 10 and 7, you'd have 20, 17 and 6. Assume the next roll comes up 3, you'd have 23, 17 and 6. Keep 2 means you'd choose two dice and the best two here are the 23 and 17 for a total roll of 40.

Comment: Okidoke! Chain reaction explosion it is.

Comment: ipso facto Sim!